# Deducing the periodicity of basis functions from the periodicity of a particular linear combination

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be linearly independent solutions for $$y''+q(t)y=0, t\in [0,\infty),$$ for some continuous periodic function $q(t)$ on $[0,\infty)$ with period $T$. Suppose that the given ODE has a  a non-trivial solution $y_*$ which is periodic with the same period $T$, then how can we calculate the value of $y_1(T)+y_2'(T)$? I feel the value is nothing but $y_1(0)+y_2'(0)$. But I cannot connect the periodicity of $y_*$ with the periodicity of $y_1$ and $y_2$. How can we use the fact $$y_*(t)=c_1y_1(t)+c_2y_2(t)=c_1y_1(t+T)+c_2y_2(t+T)$$ here?

Comment: See Floquet theory, not all solutions have to be periodic. But as one Floquet exponent is zero, and the coefficient of the first derivative is zero, there might be more information to be found.

Comment: This did indeed remind me of an older question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266352/yaxyx-0-quad-ax-is-continuous-function-with-period-t, for flavor a similar question is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878686/existence-of-periodic-solution-of-a-2nd-order-homogeneous-ode, the basics of Floquet theory in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277255/periodic-differential-equation-proof,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By linear independence there exists a matrix $A$ with
$$
\Phi(T)=A\Phi(0),~~\Phi(t)=\pmatrix{y_1(t)&y_2(t)\\y_1'(t)&y_2'(t)}.
$$
By existence and uniqueness it follows that
$$
\Phi(T+t)=A\Phi(t),~~~\Phi(nT+t)=A^n\Phi(t).
$$
This just for completeness, it is not that important for this task.

By general Wronski theory we know that $\det\Phi(t)$ is constant, as $p(t)=0$ for the coefficient of the first derivative. Thus $\det A=1$.

That a non-trivial periodic solution exists implies that $A$ has one eigenvalue $1$, and thus that this is the only eigenvalue.

Now if it were $\Phi(0)=I$, the result $y_1(T)+y_2'(T)=trace(\Phi(T))=trace(A)=2$ would follow. But we only know $A=I+N$ with some nilpotent $N$, which might be non-zero